# How do I filter a JSON output using jq with a nested sub-key value

Tags: json, jq

I am trying to use `jq` to filter the `latest` Docker Image version from a `curl` output. So far I could come up to here:

**Command**
curl https://docker.hub.example.net/api/v1.0/projects/myapp/repositories/artifacts | jq -r '(.[] | {digest, tags})'

**Output:**

Note: Some sub-keys have been removed and real values have been replaced with some example values in the output.

```
{
  "digest": "sha256:.......",
  "tags": [
    {
      "artifact_id": 123456,
      "name": "latest",
    },
    {
      "artifact_id": 123456,
      "name": "1.0.1234567890.ab12cd3",
    }
  ]
}
{
    "digest": "sha256:.......",
    "tags": [
    {
      "artifact_id": 234567,
      "name": "1.0.1234567890.bc23de4",
    }
  ]
}
{
    "digest": "sha256:.......",
    "tags": [
    {
      "artifact_id": 345678,
      "name": "1.0.1234567890.cd34ef5",
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see in the above output, only one digest has two tags with the same contents except the `name` sub-key values are different. One is `"name": "latest"` and the other is the image version (e.g. `"name": "1.0.1234567890.ab12cd3"`). Other digests have only one tag.

I need to get the image version from the digest that has the other tag with `"name": "latest"`. I prefer to avoid scripted loop, if possible, and just use the `jq` options.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `select` in combination with `any`:

```bash
curl ... | jq -r '
  .[] | select(.tags | any(.name == "latest"))
  | first(.tags[] | select(.name != "latest")).name
'
```

```json
1.0.1234567890.ab12cd3
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/xYGWo12NHH5)

Comment: @Inian I don't know what "image version" means. If it is the `.artifact_id` then replace `{digest}` with `.tags[0].artifact_id`.

Comment: Thanks @Inian for the prompt response. Sorry I could not make it clear. The "image version" meant the value of the `name` key (e.g. `"name": "1.0.1234567890.ab12cd3"`) from the second tag pared with the same digest.

Comment: @Rafiq Changed my response to output the corresponding `.name` value.